# submit button with ajax response instead of changing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that currently after pressing the submit button it changes website to echo a success message. I want when the user clicks the submit button, a message will show him that he successfully added a record, without changing the page. I think the proper way is ajax .
OPEN TO ANY SUGGESTIONS

Below is the form and php file used to insert values into the database

form

```
<div id="addForm">
     <div id="formHeading"><h2>Add Product</h2></div><p>

    <form id = "additems" action="../cms/insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"/>
      <label for="title">Title: </label><input type="text" name="title"/>
      <label for="description">Desc: </label><input type="text" name="description"/>
      <label for="price">Price: </label><input type="text" name="price" />
      <label for="stock">Quan: </label><input type="text" name="stock" />
      <p>     

<small>Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" /></small>

<div id='preview'>
</div>

     <select name="categories">
              <option value="mens">Mens</option>
              <option value="baby_books">Baby Books</option>
              <option value="comics">Comics</option>
              <option value="cooking">Cooking</option>
              <option value="games">Games</option>
              <option value="garden">Garden</option>
              <option value="infants">Infants</option>
              <option value="kids">Kids</option>
              <option value="moviestv">Movies-TV</option>
              <option value="music">Music</option>
              <option value="women">Women</option>
    </select>           
           <input type="submit" id="submit_form" name="Submit" value="Add new item">
          </form>
```

insert.php (used in the form)

```
session_start();
$session_id='1'; //$session id
$path = "../cms/uploads/";

    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
            $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

            if(strlen($name))
                {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                    {
                    if($size<(1024*1024))
                        {
                            $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                                {

$table = $_POST['categories'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$des = $_POST['description'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$stock = $_POST['stock'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO $table (title, description, price, image, stock)
    VALUES
    ('$title','$des','$price','$path$actual_image_name','$stock')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    die("1 record added into the $table table");


        }
        else
            echo "failed";
        }
        else
            echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
        }
        else
            echo "Invalid file format..";   
        }

        else
            echo "Please select image..!";

        exit;
    }
```

I have this script but i cant get it to work

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input#submit_form').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../insert.php',// TARGET PHP SCRIPT
            type: 'post',   // HTTP METHOD
            data: {
                'title' : $('input[name="title"]').val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data); // WILL SHOW THE MESSAGE THAT YOU SHOWED IN YOUR PHP SCRIPT.
            }
        });
    });
})

</script>
```

Comment: Okay, and what is the problem? Apart from the sql injection, that is...

Comment: i need an ajax form to do that isnt it?

Comment: Not really, you just need to add javascript that makes the post request and handles the results. You probably don't have to change anything in your html or php.

Comment: can you help me do that? I am kinda new on this thing

Comment: added the script i already have

Comment: As jeroen hinted, (and for brevity I left it out of my answer), you want to at least look into how to make stored procedures (emphasis on the "at least"). As your php is now, I could make your database do anything I wanted by typing MySQL right into the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. The AJAX call is probably happening, but you haven't told he button to stop its default behavior (navigating away). Here is what needs to change. Notice that I've added an `event` parameter to your callback.

```
$('input#submit_form').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Don't do your default behavior, button
    $.ajax({
        url: '../insert.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'title' : $('input[name="title"]').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        //if it breaks, you want to be able to press F12 to see why
        error: function(data){
            window.console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Even if this doesn't work and there is something else wrong with your code, you will at least be able to press F12 after submitting your form to see if there are other errors (500 errors from your php, 404 errors from a bad link, etc). It's not so easy to see what you did wrong when you are directed to the submission page immediately.

Comment: yea all i get is the echo of 1 record added into the mens table. I want to have a message that pop ups without changing page after the user clicks submit

Comment: Great, that means it works. Now you just have to tell the submit button "actually I don't want you to submit the form and take me to the echo page. My AJAX will take it from here, so you put an `event` parameter into your click handler function, and then you say `event.preventDefault()` to tell it that.

Comment: can you please write me the code because i am not very good at it?

Comment: Have a look at colorbox here, this is not a place for people to write code for you. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/

Comment: There's no need to write code. You just have to change `$('input#submit_form').on('click', function() {` to `$('input#submit_form').on('click', function(event) {`, and then underneath that put `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Not sure how colorbox solves the problem. At least read the question first.

Comment: doesn't do anything, just keeps changing the page into another page echo that 1 records was added to the table mens...